# How to write a shorter and more efficient code for a for loop with try catch retry mechanism?

Tags: java, coding-style

I have to make a function call. If it fails, I retry another 2 times. If it still fails after the 2 retrys, I throw an exception.

Below is my current code which is working:

```
for (int retry = 0; retry < 4; retry++) {
        try {
            callFunction();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (retry >= 0 && retry < 3) {
                warn("callFunction failed. Retrying.." +(retry+1));
            } else {
                warn("Retried maximum number of "+(retry+1)+" times. Failing the script");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
callFunction failed. Retrying..1
callFunction failed. Retrying..2
callFunction failed. Retrying..3
Retried maximum number of 4 times. Failing the script
```

I understand that this is not the most efficient way to code even though it is working. Can you help me refactor this code to meet the best practice standards of Java clean code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: Also, read the description for the [tag:coding-style] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's not so great here:

- The deep nesting
- The redundant `retry >= 0` condition
- The repeated `(retry + 1)`
- The repeated used of magic number 4

I think a `while` loop might flow more naturally here,
and checking at the end the retry count.

```
int maxRetries = 3;
int retry = 0;
Exception thrown = null;

while (retry < maxRetries) {
  try {
    callFunction();
    break;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    thrown = e;
    retry++;
    warn("callFunction failed. Retrying.." + retry);
  }
}

if (retry == maxRetries) {
  warn("reached max");
  thrown.printStackTrace();
}
```

Actually, it's even better if you turn this into a function.
There will be fewer variables:

```
void executeWithRetries(int maxRetries) {
  Exception thrown = null;

  for (int retry = 0; retry < maxRetries; retry++) {
    try {
      callFunction();
      return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      thrown = e;
      warn("callFunction failed. Retrying.." + retry);
    }
  }

  warn("reached max");
  thrown.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This helps. But, when I try to print the stack trace of the exception in the if (retry == maxRetries)  block, the variable 'e' is out of scope.

`if (retry == MAX_RETRY_COUNT) {

    warn("Reached maximum number of retries. Failing the script.");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }`

Comment: @InsecureNoob Ah yes. You can save it in a variable (updated my answer).

Comment: @InsecureNoob you're welcome. I added one more variation, you might like it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use a library for something like this. Using [Failsafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe):

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy().withMaxRetries(3);
Failsafe.with(retryPolicy)
  .onRetry((c, f, ctx) -> warn("callFunction failed. Retrying.." + ctx.getExecutions()))
  .onFailure(e -> {
    warn("Retried maximum number of times. Failing the script");
    e.printStackTrace();
  });
  .run(this::callFunction);
```